# Socket.io is not able to connect to server from the client side

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

Firstly my server.js side code is:

```
var socket  = require( 'socket.io' );
var requestify = require('requestify');
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var server  = require('http').createServer(app);
var io      = socket.listen( server );
var port    = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(port, function () {
 console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});
```

However, this server code is running fine in the allocated port.

Now my client side code is:

```
var socket = io.connect( 'http://'+IP_ADDRESS+':3000',          {query:'userId='+userId+'&orgId='+orgId});
 console.log(socket);
 socket.on('connect', function() {
        console.log('check 2', socket.connected);
            // alert(socket.connected);
        });
```

This is **not working** on the **live server** but working absolutely fine on local (xampp) server. The socket.on function does not respond. On the console log
the console of socket gives:

```
socket.io-client:url parse http://52.40.237.147:3000 +0ms
2017-03-08 11:20:59.026 socket.io.js:2708 socket.io-client new io 
instance for http://52.40.237.147:3000 +1ms
2017-03-08 11:20:59.030 socket.io.js:2708 socket.io-client:manager
readyState closed +2ms
2017-03-08 11:20:59.030 socket.io.js:2708 socket.io-client:manager 
opening http://52.40.237.147:3000 +3ms
2017-03-08 11:20:59.032 socket.io.js:2708 engine.io-client:socket 
creating transport "polling" +0ms
2017-03-08 11:20:59.034 socket.io.js:2708 engine.io-client:polling 
polling +1ms
2017-03-08 11:20:59.034 socket.io.js:2708 engine.io-client:polling-xhr 
xhr poll +1ms
2017-03-08 11:20:59.036 socket.io.js:2708 engine.io-client:polling-xhr 
xhr open 
GET: http://52.40.237.147:3000/socket.io/?    userId=9&orgId=3&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LgiQhOy +1ms
2017-03-08 11:20:59.037 socket.io.js:2708 engine.io-client:polling-xhr 
xhr data null +1ms
2017-03-08 11:20:59.039 socket.io.js:2708 engine.io-client:socket 
setting transport polling +3ms
2017-03-08 11:20:59.040 socket.io.js:2708 socket.io-client:manager 
connect attempt will timeout after 20000 +9ms
2017-03-08 11:20:59.041 socket.io.js:2708 socket.io-client:manager 
readyState opening +2ms
2017-03-08 11:20:59.042 (index):1022
```

Guys i could not figure out the problem. Why is'nt it connecting to the server.

Comment: The usual way to troubleshoot this would be to examine the details of the client-side network tab in the debugger.  There, you can see exactly what transpires between client and server at the network level and this will usually offer clues for why no connection is established.